# How can I make a progress indicator in a listview by coloring the background partly?

Tags: android, listview, drawing

For my podcast app I have a listview with the downloaded episodes. The user can click on one of the items and it will play. When it's finished it will play the next in the list and so on.

However, I would like to indicate the played portion by coloring the background of the row. I do not want a progress bar widget. So lets say the user has played half of the epsiode, then the left half of the row should have say a green background color.

Unfortunately, I have no ideas how to implement that although it sounds quite simple.

Here is my code so far. playPostion is a number from 0 to 1000 that gives the relative position, so 500 is halfways played etc.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.player_row_view,
        c,
        new String[] {"title","date","hour"},
        new int[] {R.id.playertitle, R.id.playerdate, R.id.playerhour}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                int playPosition = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("position"));
                // playPosition contains the position
                return row;
        }

};
```

**How can change the background of the current row according to the playPosition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be having a FrameLayout, with two layouts on top of each other. You could then use one for background and the other for foreground.

In the background layout you should have two layouts. One with the default color and one with the progress color. When you want to update progress, remove the layouts currently in the background and replace them with two new layouts with layout_weight set according to your progress values e.g. if the progress is 500 you would have each set to layout_weight="0.500f".

I don't think it's the best solution - but if you don't want to use a ProgressBar, this is probably the direction you need to take.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. However, I simplified it a bit by having only one linear layout inside the background container. Instead of changing the layout weights, I simply changed the paddingRight for the container according to the progess value. But the main idea is the same.

Comment: Btw, I also tried setting the width of the progess layout at runtime which seemed to be the simplest solution instead of using padding, but for some reason I wasn't allowed to change the layout params; I got an exception **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams**

Comment: @marlar, Please can you clarify what is the meaning of background container? Also can you provide the source which will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to wrap your row item into `FrameLayout` and add a `ProgressBar` to it, so it would be on background. Then you'd be able to manage that bar setting progress as you want.

Comment: This worked too although it took a lot of tweeaking of the progress bar to make it look right: setting the background to none, removing the gradients and rounded corners etc. That's why I didn't want to use the progress bar in the first place. However, I did take it all to the end although it took several hours, but I learned a lot about customizing widgets using drawables etc. So +1 for the answer!